# When toggling WebVR on iPhone, an empty video shows up

Tags: ios, cordova, webvr, krpano

I've got a problem with a vtour generated from KRPano 1.19-pr16 when clicking on the VR icon on iPhone.

The vTour has simply been generated via the droplet and a static 360 image and encapsulated in Cordova. On any browser, clicking the VR icon toggles the WebVR on and that's it.

On iPhones, an empty video displays when I tap on the VR icon and I have to close the said video before accessing VR. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering why a video shows up and how to avoid this, here's the [official forum post where Klaus answered me](https://krpano.com/forum/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&postID=75574)

> that's the 'ios wakelock' hack - it play a 'hidden' video in the background to avoid that Safari would let the device go into sleep mode.
>
> There are two solutions for custom apps (both should be applied):
>
> Enable the 'allowsInlineMediaPlayback' setting in your app:
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentatio…nemediaplayback
>   This would avoid that the browser would open the build-in fullscreen videoplayer when playing the 'wakelock' video.
>
> And better also disable the 'wakelock' hack of the krpano WebVR plugin:
>   https://krpano.com/plugins/webvr/#mobilevr_wakelock
>   and disable the device-sleep-mode directly in your app.